# Mongoose Discriminators unable to add dicriminator details

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Im currently working on adding discriminators to my express rest api. I have added different types of users to the user schema using the discriminators as different user require additional information. The problem I am facing is that when I post to the api get no errors when adding the information and only the general information is added to the schema, the details within the discriminators are ignored.

The schema is as follows:

```
var options = { discriminatorKey: 'type' };

var UserSchema = new Schema({
local: {
    email: {
        type: String,
        sparse: true,
        lowercase: true,
    },
    password: { type: String },
},
facebook: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    email: String,
    name: String,
    profileIMG: String,
},
twitter: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    displayName: String,
    username: String
},
google: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    email: String,
    name: String,
    profileIMG: String,
}
}, options);

var addressSubschema = {
  street: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  number: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
};

var workingHoursSchema = {
  start: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  finish: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
};

var adminSchema = new Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  workingHours: workingHoursSchema,
  address: addressSubschema,
  workingRadius: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
}, options);
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
var Admin = User.discriminator('AdminUser', adminSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

I then export the model and when saving a new user I get a success however the admin details are not saved.

```
User.findOne({'local.email': email}, function(err, existingUser) {

if (err) { return next(err) }
if (existingUser) {return res.status(422).json({error: "Email already exists"})}

var user = new User({
  "local.email": req.body.email,
  "local.password": req.body.password,
  "description": req.body.description,
  "category": req.body.category,
  "workingRadius": req.body.workingRadius,
  "street": req.body.street,
  "number": req.body.number,
  "city": req.body.city,
  "start": req.body.start,
  "finish": req.body.finish
});

user.save(function(err) {
  if (err) { return next(err) }
  res.json({success: true});
});

});
```

Im new to using the discriminator so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question is titled with discriminators and there is nothing here showing discriminators being set up. Models apply discriminators please! Also mention of POST data. Nothing showing that happening either. Please post more infomation. At the very least so we can work out what the question is you are actually asking.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry, I've added more details